# Fibonacci and 'if constexpr'

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement, c++17, constexpr

Please consider this code:

```
template<int nIndex>
int Fibonacci()
{
    if constexpr (nIndex == 0) return 0;
    if constexpr (nIndex == 1) return 1;

    static_assert(nIndex >= 0, "Invalid index passed to Fibonacci()");
    return Fibonacci<nIndex - 1>() + Fibonacci<nIndex - 2>();
}

int main()
{
    Fibonacci<3>(); // 2
    //Fibonacci<-1>();  // Fires assertion 

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this in VS2017, the compiler outputs:

```
error C2338: Invalid index passed to Fibonacci()
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int Fibonacci<-1>(void)' being compiled
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int Fibonacci<1>(void)' being compiled
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int Fibonacci<3>(void)' being compiled
```

This is not what I expect; I expect the result to be 2.  Am I using `if constexpr` incorrectly here?

Furthermore, I don't understand the compiler's diagnostic message.

```
Fib(3) = Fib(2)              + Fib(1)
       = Fib(1) + Fib(0)
       = 1      + 0          + 1
       = 2
```

So why is the compiler thinking that Fib(-1) is being called?

Comment: You [forgot to use `else` branches of the `if constexpr` statements](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3LNQqgbbOommFYHs).

Comment: OK, so I have put an else before the second `if constexpr` and an `else` before the `static_assert` and final `return` statement and it works.  But I am missing something fundamental here, I thought after the compiler hit the first `return` it would just not execute anything else...or do I misunderstand `if constexpr`?

Comment: The code outside both branches of the `if constexpr` compiles unconditionally so both `Fibonacci<nIndex - 1>()` and `Fibonacci<nIndex - 2>` should be compiled even for `nIndex == 0` and `nIndex == 1` in your variant of the code.

Comment: But why doesn't compilation "stop" after the `return` statement in 'if constexpr (nIndex == 0) return 0;` I mean, I can see that it doesn't but I don't understand why...

Comment: I don't know what rationale stays behind such behavior.

Comment: BTW: if you're using `if constexpr`, then you don't need to use templates at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So why is the compiler thinking that Fib(-1) is being called?

It doesn't; it thinks that it has been *instantiated* (or more specifically, `Fibonacci<-1>` has been).

What you want is conditional instantiation. That can only be achieved if the statements that instantiate the template are themselves governed by `if constexpr` statements:

```
template<int nIndex>
int Fibonacci()
{
    static_assert(nIndex >= 0, "Invalid index passed to Fibonacci()");

    if constexpr (nIndex == 0) return 0;
    else if constexpr (nIndex == 1) return 1;
    else
      return Fibonacci<nIndex - 1>() + Fibonacci<nIndex - 2>();
}
```

If `nIndex` is 0 or 1, then the code in the final return statement will not cause templates to be instantiated.

Comment: OK, so what you are saying is that when Fib(3) is executed, the compiler knows this is Fib(2) + Fib(1), so it seems it executes Fib(1) first, and when doing so doesn't "stop" after the first return statement in `if constexpr (nIndex == 0) return 0;`, instead it goes on to execute Fib(0) + Fib(-1) via `return Fibonacci<nIndex - 1>() + Fibonacci<nIndex - 2>();` the latter of which is what gives the compiler output - *have I understood that correctly?*

Comment: @Wad: No. It's not about what gets executed. It's about what gets *instantiated*. You keep typing `Fib(1)`, when what's actually happening is `Fibonacci<1>()`. Those aren't the same thing. The latter is template instantiation. If the statement `Fibonacci<-1>` appears *anywhere in the program*, then the program will fail to compile, due to the static assert.

Comment: Right, yes I see.  OK, so you are saying that when I instantiate `Fibonacci<3>()`, that causes the instantiation of `Fibonacci<2>()` and `Fibonacci<1>()`.  So it seems from my compiler output that `Fibonacci<1>()` then gets instantiated first before `Fibonacci<2>()`, which, due to there being no `else` statements in my original code, causes `Fibonacci<0>()` and `Fibaonacci<-1>()` to be instantiated...hence my error.  Is this correct understanding?